# Run multiple spiders, using scraped urls from database as start_urls

Tags: mongodb, scrapy

I am doing a scrapy project, using multiple spider.I am using different spiders, because the scraped content is completely different for each spider.

I am using this code to run my (4) spiders:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


setting = get_project_settings()
process = CrawlerProcess(setting)

for spider_name in process.spiders.list():
    print ("Running spider %s" % (spider_name))
    process.crawl(spider_name, query="dvh") 

process.start()
```

The code works fine, but the issue is that my start_urls for spider 2,3 and 4 are dynamic. I get the start_urls from mongodb.

`start_urls = client.db.collection.distinct("urls_scraped_by_previous_spider")`

The main issue is that when `process.crawl(spider_name, query="dvh")` loads ALL spiders (and start_urls) but the database does not contain the urls yet. Thus the script will end after running the first spider.

I also tried:

```
def start_requests(self):
    self.start_urls += client.db.collection.distinct("urls_scraped_by_previous_spider")
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
            endpoint='render.json',
            args={'html': 1,'har':1,'wait': 2.5}
        )
```

Comment: maybe first run only first spider and later run others. Or create only one spider.

Comment: The spiders scrape thousand of pages, if I run them separately I can't run them unattended overnight. Creating one spider isn't really an option, considering the amount of code in my spiders

Comment: if spider2,3,4 need data from spider1 then you have to run spider1 earlier - maybe 5 minutes earlier will be enought.

Comment: or maybe run spider2,3,4 in some loop so it will runs again and again with some delay. And spider1 can add new data meanwhile.

Comment: Spider 2 takes data from 1, spider 3 takes output from spider 2 and so on...

Comment: and this is why I was thinking about one spider which get data using `parser()` and execute `Request()` which uses `parser()` from spider2,  and it execute `Request()` which uses `parser()` from spider3, etc

Comment: or if spider1 will run all the time and add data, and spider2 will run from time to time and check if there are new data to create new results in new place,  and spider3 will run from time to time and check if spider2 generete new data, etc.

Comment: use scrapyd to schedule the spiders, and set it to run only 1 spider at a time